# Como pegar valores de uma linha que estão em uma lista jstl e enviar para dentro dos respectivos input text na mesma pagina jsp?

Tags: java, servlet, jstl

Boa tarde pessoal!Estou usando "Jsp, servlets, e jstl". Tenho uma lista onde tenho um link chamado alterar, ao clicar Pego os valores daquela linha da lista e envio para a mesma jsp onde tem um form  com os campos para poder ser feita a alteração, até o momento só estou conseguindo fazer os valores aparecerem na url pagina, mas não consigo exibi-los nos campos da jsp.

Estou enviando os campos  desta forma

```
<td> <a href="view/v_configura_turma.jsp?&id_turma=${listat.turma_id}&nome_turma="${listat.tur_nome}></a>  </td>
```

E recebendo na outra jsp desta forma

```
<div>
   <input type="text" name="id_turma" id="id_turma" readonly="true" class="form-control" placeholder="Registro da turma" required="" value="${param.turma_id}"/>
</div>
</br>
<div>
    <input type= "text" name="nome_turma" id="tur_nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome da turma" required="" value="${param.tur_nome}" />
</div>
```

está e a URL que está chegando na outra pagina

http://localhost:43183/Chamada_online/view/v_configura_turma.jsp?&id_turma=1&nome_turma=TESTE5

Desde já agradeço!! Ainda estou aprendendo a usar o stackoverflow caso minha pergunta esteja mal formatada editarei de pronto :)

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde pessoal, não consegui fazer de forma direta , então simplesmente peguei o  id da linha selecionada e fiz uma nova consulta no banco onde recuperei os valores e  inserir os mesmos no input text para fazer as alterações.

Minha jsp na requisição da linha da  lista ficou desta forma.

```
<td> <a href="./Turma_conf?funcao=recebe&id_turma=${listat.turma_id}/></td>
```

Meu servlet ficou desta forma ,ele recebe um parâmetro  onde  é escolhida a função a ser executada.

```
String funcao = request.getParameter("funcao");
```

Executo a função **recebe** onde a mesma envia  para o método DAO onde é feita a pesquisa por id e recebendo os valores da  mesma como retorno para o servlet e na sequência  enviado  para a jsp preenchendo os campos.

O como ficou meu servlet  abaixo.

```
if(funcao.equals("recebe")){            
                    int turma_id = Integer.parseInt( request.getParameter("id_turma"));                                                                         
                    tb = tur.turma_busca_pk(turma_id);
                    request.setAttribute("turma", tb);                                           
                    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("configura_turma.jsp");
                    rd.forward(request, response);
```

Meu método DAO segue abaixo caso ajuda  mais gente em pesquisa por id.
ele recebe o id e faz a consulta no banco de dados recebendo 8 parâmetros de retorno.

```
public TurmmaBean turma_busca_pk (int id_turma){
    TurmmaBean turma = new TurmmaBean();
    String sql  ="select * from turma where tur_turma_id ="+id_turma;
    try {
    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql); 
    rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);
   if (rs.next()){

            turma.setTurma_id(rs.getInt("tur_turma_id"));
            turma.setTur_nome(rs.getString("tur_nome"));
            turma.setTur_diciplina(rs.getString("tur_diciplina"));
            turma.setTur_ini_dia( new java.sql.Date (rs.getDate("tur_inicio").getTime()));
            turma.setTur_fim_dia(new java.sql.Date(rs.getDate("tur_fim").getTime()));
            turma.setTur_hora_inicio(rs.getTime("tur_hora_inicio"));
            turma.setTur_hora_fim(rs.getTime("tur_hora_fim"));
            turma.setTur_dia_semana(rs.getString("tur_dia_semana"));

   }
           rs.close();
           ps.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Erro 1_D   " + e);
      }

return turma;
}
```

Desde já muito obrigado  galera!!!! :) Boas festas de fim de 2018.